# Почему дает Exception на нулевой объект

Tags: c#, sql-server

Просто хочу извлекать данные из БД но вот здесь

```
maskedTextBox1.Text = animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.Value.ToString();
```

ругается бросает такое исключение

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Нулевой объект должен иметь значение.
```

Comment: Null object must have a value. Т.е. правая часть выражения возвращает null.

Comment: "Т.е. правая часть выражения возвращает null."???

Comment: Одна из ссылок: `animal`, `animal.animalQuery`, `animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day`, `animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.Value` или `maskedTextBox1` имеет значение `null`.

Comment: да это столбец из БД,где разрешается null,

Comment: вот это `animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day`

Comment: @Igor, ну глупо предполагать что TextBox контрол, брошенный на форму - имеет значение null. Так что как раз "правая часть выражения" и означает что одна из "ссылок" == null.

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, какой тип у _animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day_? если это какой-то nullable - то не нужно брать свойство _Value_ достаточно вызвать _ToSrting_: `animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте `Value`:

```
maskedTextBox1.Text = (animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.Value == null)? 
  "" : animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.Value.ToString();
```

или

```
maskedTextBox1.Text = 
  System.Convert.ToString(animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.Value);
```

Comment: написал, и получилось  `Value`  для условии не нужно надо проверять `animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day`

Comment: вот так  `maskedTextBox1.Text = (animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day == null)? 
  "" : animal.animalQuery.fructify_Day.Value.ToString();`

Comment: спасибо за поддержку  ;)

Comment: @VardanVardanyan - Отлично, молодец.